# Android Studio: Exit code 2 with emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

The android studio emulator cannot run, and I get this error:

```
Emulator: [4516]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at C:\Users\School\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
Emulator: Could not launch 'C:\Users\School\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 2
```

The android studio version is 3.1.4 for Windows 64-bit.  Please help me fix this!

Comment: Possible cause: Emulator is not installed on your PC.. open AVD Manager re-download the package and rerun it.

Comment: It is possible you downloaded the emulator in a path different from the one recognised above. If this is the issue, just copy the exe file and paste it in the path specified above

Answer (score 7):

Go to:

```
Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
```

On Android Studio and try installing Android Emulator:

[image]

However, if this didn't help, Go to `-> AVD Manager` from Android Studio, Redownload the AVD image and then error should be gone.

Comment: Hello! I tried downloading android emulator, and was met with a "tag mismatch." I looked online and tried using the "force https:// sources to be fetched using http://" option in SDK update sites, but it still didn't work. What might be causing this?

Comment: Never mind, it downloaded after trying 5 times, haha. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!